# Add a geojson file on a OSM map

Tags: ajax, openstreetmap, geojson

I want to put a geojson file on my open street map for have a marker ( place )

my geojson file looks like :

```
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "@id": "way\/76732062", "access": "customers", "amenity": "bicycle_parking", "bicycle_pa": "shed", "building": "yes", "capacity": "45", "name": "Vélopole - Les Près", "source": "cadastre-dgi-fr source : Direction Générale des Impôts - Cadastre. Mise à jour : 2009", "operator": null, "network": null, "surveillan": null, "wall": null, "covered": null, "supervised": null, "fee": null, "lit": null, "level": null }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 708894.79501892452, 7061474.7829677835 ] } },
```

being a junior developer I absolutely do not know how to add this file to my map

i see many exmaples like :

```
$.getJSON("http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_day.geojson", function(data) { addDataToMap(data, map); });
```

but I do not know how to adapt it to my code

Thank's in advance for ur answer !

Comment: you can see the full code here : view-source:carto.droitauvelo.org/new

Comment: What is "your map"? Are you using Leaflet, OpenLayers, something else? Either way, read the GeoJSON response and add a marker for each entry on the given lat, lon coordinates.

Comment: Thanks for answering but I managed to add a geojson file simply with L.geoJSON

Comment: So your are using Leaflet...